# What do '|', '?', '+', '*', and ',' mean in a DTD file?

Tags: xml, dtd

I found a lot of these kind of codes in DTD files (each line from a separated DTD file) :

```
<!ELEMENT master (big | small)*>
<!ELEMENT master (big* | small*)>
<!ELEMENT master (big+, small*)>
<!ELEMENT master (big, small)*>
<!ELEMENT master (big, small+)*>
<!ELEMENT master (big | small+)*>
<!ELEMENT master (big | small+)>
<!ELEMENT master (big? | small+)>`
```

I understand the basics like `<!Element Master`  and what `big` and `small` means, but what I don't get is what `|`  `?` `+` `*` `,` etc means.  Also what does it mean when it's between `()` ?

NOTE : each line is taken from a separated DTD file. (I copied each line from 9 DTD files.)
What does each line mean?

Comment: Maybe these are regular expressions?

Comment: What do they mean ? Whats the indication ?

Comment: @NicoHaase, no, but their semantics are similar.  See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69789140/290085)

Answer (score 4):

Most of those operators have their usual meaning in computer science as used, for example, in regular expressions, EBNF, etc:

- `a | b` means `a` or `b`
- `a?` means optionally `a`
- `a*` means zero or more `a`
- `a+` means one or more `a`

`a, b` means a sequence of `a` followed by `b`.

Answer (score 3):

To take one example

```
<!ELEMENT master (big, small+)*>
```

means that a valid `master` element has a content that consists of a sequence of zero or more groups, where each group contains one element named `big` followed by one or more elements called `small`.

Google for "XML DTD tutorial" and you will find plenty of more detailed explanations.